# Branch.io - Export Credits Data out of Branch

Tags: branch.io

Is there a way to export credits data out of branch.io - either via APIs or manually?
I've tried

(1) APIs:
`https://api.branch.io/v1/credits?branch_key=<key>&identity=<dev_id>`
but I need something like 
`https://api.branch.io/v1/credits?branch_key=<key>&date=20180528` (extract based on date or date range).

(2) Manual CSV download - there doesn't seem to be a credits download option anywhere?

Also tried the data Export API which only has the following items for download:
`eo_branch_cta_view,
eo_click
eo_commerce_event
eo_custom_event
eo_install
eo_open
eo_pageview
eo_reinstall
eo_sms_sent
eo_web_session_start`

Please, can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Currently, it is not possible to export all the credits data. You can only access the credit history for each user using the API endpoint you mentioned.

Comment: Yep, need more from their API.

Answer (score 0):

This is Vatsal, from [Branch.io](https://branch.io)!

Our new Liveview currently is in the process of supporting Credits Exports. For now, you can temporarily switch back to the old version of the Liveview and download the Credits exports as before. To do that, you can append "**?pba_liveview=false**" like this: https://dashboard.branch.io/liveview/credits?pba_liveview=false

To switch back, you can set https://dashboard.branch.io/liveview/credits?pba_liveview=true

Hope this helps.